# Amazon API call to get number of listed products on page

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, asp.net-core

Is it possible to get count of listed products in an Amazon page?

[image]

I need to get this number. I know I can use javascript to get it by ID or class, but I know that amazon changes the values of IDs and classes in some period of time, so later on I wouldn't be able to get this number unless I check the ID or class by myself and change it in code.. So is there an API call or something to freely get this number, without changing code every time?

Comment: could you give a  example URL?

Answer (score 0):

You need a combination of `ItemSearch` and the `ResponseGroup` `BrowseNodes`. It would be something like this if you were to use C# and pass the results back to your JavaScript app:

```
ItemSearchRequest request = new ItemSearchRequest();
request.ResponseGroup = new string[] { "BrowseNodes", "ItemAttributes" };
request.SearchIndex = "Movies";
request.Keywords = "game of thrones";

ItemSearch search = new ItemSearch();
search.AWSAccessKeyId = access_key_id;
search.AssociateTag = associate_tag;
search.Request = new ItemSearchRequest[] { request };

AWSECommerceServicePortTypeClient port = new AWSECommerceServicePortTypeClient("AWSECommerceServicePort");
port.ChannelFactory.Endpoint.EndpointBehaviors.Add(new AmazonSigningEndpointBehavior(access_key_id, secret_access_key));

ItemSearchResponse response = port.ItemSearch(search);
foreach (var items in response.Items)
{
    foreach (var item in items.Item)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0}\t{1}\t{2}", item.ItemAttributes.Title, item.ASIN, item.ItemAttributes.Author[0]);

        if (item.BrowseNodes != null)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(" - BrowseNodes");
            foreach (var node in item.BrowseNodes)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" -- \t{0}\t{1}\t{2}", node.TotalResults);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- https://flyingpies.wordpress.com/2009/08/01/17/
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/LocaleUS.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/ItemSearch.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSECommerceService/latest/DG/RG_BrowseNodes.html